# Substrate Rust generate key pair using sp_core::crypto::Pair

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new with Substrate and Rust, but I was trying to generate a key pair using the `from_string` function of `sp_core::crypto::Pair` . I haven't had any luck and kept getting either `InvalidHexString` or `InvalidPhrase` errors when I try to pass valid key items generated from the `subkey` tool.

For instance, I generated these key items from subkey tool by running the cmd `subkey generate`:

```
Secret phrase:       endorse doctor arch helmet master dragon wild favorite property mercy vault maze
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0x78b8fbbbea218509c00d3531e72128d4eae54089f15deb24d721e30b351733ad
  Public key (hex):  0x14e121f6e6cc2891cbbd5f6692e3724672d13e93a3562e3905d4310c2ba1c510
  Account ID:        0x14e121f6e6cc2891cbbd5f6692e3724672d13e93a3562e3905d4310c2ba1c510
  Public key (SS58): 5CY5hAGkTB7RZrouimGJ3S7zTDtnE6yg7z41DHrQeBcoc1PN
  SS58 Address:      5CY5hAGkTB7RZrouimGJ3S7zTDtnE6yg7z41DHrQeBcoc1PN
```

When I pass in the secret phrase I got from subkey tool to the `from_string` function, I get an `InvalidPhrase` error when submitting the composed extrinsic, even tho it was generated from subkey. This is sample code below:

```rust
  let priv_key: String = "endorse/doctor/arch/helmet/master/dragon/wild/favorite/property/mercy/vault/maze".to_owned();
  let from = Pair::from_string(&priv_key[..], None).unwrap();
  //let from = AccountKeyring::Bob.pair();
  let api = Api::new(client).map(|api| api.set_signer(from)).unwrap();
  ....
  extrinsic_submitters::submit_to_save_item(api, incoming_item, now, datetime);
```

This is the error I get upon submission of extrinsic:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidPhrase', src/services/route_actions/mod.rs:76:53
```

I get similar error when using the secret seed as argument for `from_string`, only difference is I get `InvalidHexString` error when submitting the composed extrinsic. I was trying to follow the documentation of `from_string` usage in this link: https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/sp_core/crypto/trait.Pair.html

Any tips on this on how to make this work? I was thinking the items I generated were valid. My goal was to be able to pass in a valid secret phrase or secret seed in this code to generate a key pair. I would then like to be able to sign an extrinsic using the generated key pair before passing the extrinsic to the chain. Thanks, all!

EDIT:
I just want to note that the secret phrases and secret seeds I added here aren't used in production...

Comment: Any reason for using a forward slash in your string?

Comment: Oh yeah I get an `InvalidFormat` error if I don't put forward slash on the secret phrase. With `/` characters, I get `InvalidPhrase`, so I think thats kinda better. Also, my understanding from the `Pair` documentation was that I need to separate the words for the mnemonics with `/` character. I may have understood the `Pair` docs wrong tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a concrete `Pair` implementation, since the `Pair` from `sp_core::crypto` is just a trait.
`sr25519` is the default of subkey. By using that it produces the same address that you saw in the console.
No need for `/` or anything, just the `from_string` method and `None` as password.

```rust
#[test]
fn test_from_string() {
    use sp_core::{sr25519, Pair};
    let pair = sr25519::Pair::from_string("endorse doctor arch helmet master dragon wild favorite property mercy vault maze", None).unwrap();
    
    let want = "14e121f6e6cc2891cbbd5f6692e3724672d13e93a3562e3905d4310c2ba1c510 (5CY5hAGk...)";
    let got = format!("{:?}", pair.public());
    assert_eq!(want, got);
}
```

Comment: I get `InvalidHexString(InvalidStringLength)` when I submit the extrinsic I have signed with the key pair generated from this approach.. Any clues why this might be happening? I'm pretty sure the `key pair` generated is of the same type as `AccountKeyring::Bob.pair()`. `AccountKeyring::Bob.pair()` works, but the one I generated doesn't... Your code works tho

Comment: Perhaps my actual issue is different from what I was thinking when I opened this question..

Comment: Maybe you encode the extrinsic incorrectly? You can look at the line that the error appears in your code.