# How to generate a new account with seed using rust?

Tags: account, sr25519, ed25519

I tried the following code, using method `generate`.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/crypto/trait.Pair.html#method.generate

```
use sp_core::{
    sr25519,
    ed25519,
    Pair,
};

use std::str;

fn main() {
    let pair_seed = <sp_core::ed25519::Pair as Pair>::generate();
    let (pair, seed)  = pair_seed;
    println!("{:?}", str::from_utf8(&seed).unwrap());    
}
```

Not sure `seed` is the mnemonic phrase. How to get the mnemonic phrase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substrate Rust generate key pair using sp\_core::crypto::Pair](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2285/94)

Answer (score 0):

The generate method generates a new random keypair and does not accept a seed as input. If you want to generate a new account with a specific seed, you can use the from_seed method instead.

```
use sp_core::{sr25519, ed25519, Pair};

fn main() {
    let mnemonic_phrase = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12";
    let seed = sp_core::ed25519::Seed::from_phrase(mnemonic_phrase, "")
        .expect("Invalid mnemonic phrase");
    let pair = <sp_core::ed25519::Pair as Pair>::from_seed(&seed);
    println!("{:?}", pair);
}
```

This will generate a new account using the given seed, which should be a 12-word mnemonic phrase.

Note that the Seed type is specific to the ed25519 implementation of the Pair trait, so you may need to use a different type if you are using a different curve (e.g. sr25519::Seed for the sr25519 curve).

Comment: I want to use subkey generate in my rust code, so that I can get accountId, seedphrase https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/utils/subkey#json-output

Comment: subkey is a command line tool, not sure how to use in my rust code.

Comment: Ya, used tiny-bip39 to generate the seed. https://crates.io/crates/tiny-bip39